# how to transform a flattened json data to a taxonomy string?

Tags: python

I have a data like this, aka **input data**:

```
data = ['a-aa-aab', 'a-aa-aaa', 'b-ba', 'a-aa-aab-aaba', 'a-aa-aab-aabb']
```

And I want to transform that to the taxonomy string like this, aka **output data**:

```
root a b
a a-aa
a-aa a-aa-aab a-aa-aaa
a-aa-aab a-aa-aab-aaba a-aa-aab-aabb
b b-ba
```

I think there is a recursive solution in this sample, but I don't know how to achive this target. If you happen to know the answer, please tell me, god bless you!

Comment: Hello, I don't really understand the pattern in the data. What is the processing giving the output according the input data? Could you give more details on the process you'd like to apply?

Comment: Hi, thank your attention~ the taxonomy data is going to be used in a multi-label classification task, it's a NLP(Natural Language Processing) task. And this taxonomy data is needed in our hierarchical multi-label classifier algorithm. If you want more details about this algorithm, you can browse this site: https://github.com/Tencent/NeuralNLP-NeuralClassifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = ['a-aa-aab', 'a-aa-aaa', 'b-ba', 'a-aa-aab-aaba', 'a-aa-aab-aabb']
result = defaultdict(set)
for string in data:
    parts = string.split('-')
    for i in range(len(parts)):
        key = '-'.join(parts[:i])
        val = '-'.join(parts[:i+1])
        result[key].add(val)

print(result)
for prefix, children in result.items():
    print(prefix or 'root', *children)
```

Comment: It is unbelievable! God Bless You!